# Future[Source] pipeTo an Actor

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

There are two local actors (the remoting is not used). Actors were simplified for the example:

```
class ProcessorActor extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case src:Source[Int, NotUsed] =>
      //TODO processing of `src` here
  }
}

class FrontendActor extends Actor {
  val processor = context.system.actorOf(Props[ProcessorActor])
  ...

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case "Hello" =>
      val f:Future[Source[Int, NotUsed]] = Future (Source(1 to 100))

      f pipeTo processor
  }
}

// entry point:
val frontend = system.actorOf(Props[FrontendActor])
frontend ! "Hello"
```

Thus the `FrontendActor` sends `Source` to `ProcessorActor`. In the above example it is works successfully.

Is such approach okay?

Comment: does it work four you?. You are building a Future from a akka.stream.Source... right? without creating a RunnableGraph??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Thus the `FrontendActor` sends `Source` to `ProcessorActor`. In the above example it is works successfully.
>
> Is such approach okay?

It's unclear what your concern is.

Sending a `Source` from one actor to another actor *on the same JVM* is fine. Because inter-actor communication on the same JVM, as the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/serialization.html#serialization) states, "is simply done via reference passing," there is nothing unusual about your example<sup>1</sup>. Essentially what is going on is that a reference to a `Source` is passed to `ProcessorActor` once the `Future` is completed. A `Source` is an object that defines part of a stream; you can send a `Source` from one actor to another actor *locally* just as you can any JVM object.

(However, once you cross the boundary of a single JVM, you have to deal with serialization.)

---

<sup>1</sup> A minor, tangential observation: `FrontendActor` calls `context.system.actorOf(Props[ProcessorActor])`, which creates a top-level actor. Typically, top-level actors are created in the main program, not within an actor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is OK, but does not work quite how you describe it. `FrontendActor` does not send `Future[Source]`, it just sends `Source`.

From the docs:

> pipeTo installs an onComplete-handler on the future to affect the submission of the result to another actor.

In other words, `pipeTo` means "send the result of this `Future` to the actor when it becomes available".

Note that this will work even if remoting is being used because the `Future` is resolved locally and is not sent over the wire to a remote actor.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is my mistake in description of the topic. Thanks. I've fixed it. But the main question - is about sending `Source` from an actor to another actor.